# Push variable to array through ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, session-variables

**What I am trying to do**
I have a PHP script that runs everytime it's called by my main javascript via an Ajax function. With that function, a variable 'userID' (only a number) is sent. Every time this Ajax function is called, the variable might be different and I want these saved to an array called userBack and then save them as a session cookie.

So, as an example:

First time the script is run the array is: **1**
Next time the script is run it's: **14**
Next time it's: **142**, and so forth.

**Problem**
However, it seems my script only saves the first variable sent and does not add the subsequence ones, thus behaves like a normal variable and not like an array, which I want it to.

**PHP**

```
$userBack = array();
array_push($userBack, $_POST['userID']);
$_SESSION["userBack"] = $userBack;
```

Comment: that's because you are using php for pushing the elements which is only processed on the server end and the variable avaiable is just the first one. you need to use array.push in javascript to achieve this.

Comment: Instead of just `$userBack = array();`, check if the `$_SESSION["userBack"]` is set and not empty, if so, then assign the session value to `$userBack` like `$userBack = $_SESSION["userBack"]`

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal Thank you for your comment, I can see what you mean. How would you suggest doing this through javascript?

Comment: so you may be doing an ajax call somewhere. Once you have the data from ajax call just use `arr.push(data)` where arr is array and data is the data received by the ajax call

Comment: Ah, I sadly cannot do that, as my ajax succes fuction is a json array compiling all rows needed from my database, splitting them up like id = json.id; and so on. Anyways, what you would do is, when I have recieved the variable in my jquery/java: var userBack = [] and then userBack.push (id); - Or am I misunderstanding?